# Редактор GUI

Tags: gui, ide, java, netbeans

Когда в netbeans создаешь проект из исходников, где GUI создавался не в netbeans, а, например, написан вручную. Возможно ли открыть стандартный редактор GUI в netbeans? И если нельзя, то в какой IDE это возможно сделать?

Comment: думаю, что нет, это собственно и не зачем. используйте swing и делайте все ручками, так и проще, и лучше.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но я думаю что, проще делать GUI в редакторе, а не ручками. Потому я и хочу выяснить способы это сделать, если ничего не получится, буду делать ручками.

Answer (score 1):

Для eclipse есть много плагинов, попробуй [window builder](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/windowbuilder-pro-gui-designer)

Answer (score 0):

Юзай Eclipse + Swing/SWT плагин.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую этот вариант. И заодно eclipse поучу.